# How to wrap long point label of radar chart for apache Echart?

Tags: javascript, echarts, radar-chart

Hi I work on radar apache echart, below is small piece of code. It work fine but I have problem for long point label. I would like to wrap them for short instead long single line.

```
radar: {
    name: {
        textStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            backgroundColor: '#999',
            borderRadius: 3,
            padding: [3, 5]
        }
    },
    indicator: [
        { name: 'sale', max: 6500},
        { name: '**I have problem for very long label. I need to wrap this line instead singgle long**', max: 16000},
        { name: 'Information Techology', max: 30000},
        { name: 'Customer Support', max: 38000},
        { name: 'Development', max: 52000},
        { name: 'Marketing', max: 25000}
    ]
},
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are running into this issue: https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/13551